# От чего <li> при заданном параметре position:fixed смешиваются в одну строку?

Tags: html, css

Задал `li` параметр `position:fixed`, для того, чтобы при скролле они "ездили" по блоку в котором находятся, но в результате, при применении `position:fixed`, все `li` смешиваются в кучу так, что видна только одна последняя кнопка:

```css
ul {
  padding-top: 11px;
}

.spisok {
  height: 100px;
  width: 238px;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  /*margin-top: -73%;*/
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px solid #000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}

.spisok li {
  width: 195px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 13.2px;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
  color: rgba(222, 222, 222 .1);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}

.spisok ul li a p {
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.text-div {
  width: 158px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spisok">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" id="oblacheniya" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/oblacheniya.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Облачения</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/podrizniki.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Подризники</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/stihari.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Стихари</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/ryasi.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing, ryasi">Рясы</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/podryasniki.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Подрясники</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/golovniye_ubori.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Головные уборы</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/for_monahov.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Для монахов</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/kresh_nabory.php">
        <p>Крещальные наборы</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/vench_nabory.php">
        <p>Венчальные наборы</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/obl_for_hrama.php">
        <p>Облачения для храма</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/vishitiye_kresty.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Вышитые кресты</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="ugol">
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/ugol.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Кадильный уголь</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: В Вашем сниппете нет ни одного `li`

Comment: Где Ваш li в html? Покажите код html

Comment: Извините, забыл, что он через php подключается, сейчас залью в главный пост

Comment: Готово, код залит)

Comment: 0) Сделайте **минимально** воспроизводимый пример. Сброс стилей и простыня на пять страниц отобьёт любое желание вникнуть и помочь. 1) Уберите куски `PHP` и забейте их заглушками, если нужно. 2) Вставка в один сниппет, нет смысла разделять по двум.

Comment: Вроде получилось что-то изобразить. @QuickBrownFox, запустите сниппет(кнопка "Выполнить код") и скажите - это и есть Ваша проблема?

Comment: Quick Brown Fox, ты ( приказал ) всем элементам стоять на одном месте, а какой ты реакции ждал от   position:fixed... ?

Comment: @Air я хотел, чтобы пункты меню по их div'у перемещались. Вроде бы всё правильно сделал?)

Comment: нуууу,  что дальше...?  вот  со стороны, перечитай свой вопрос, заголовок...  допустим, ты не знаешь сути проблемы...  я в твоем вопросе не вижу вопроса...

Comment: Для чего вообще вы сделали `position: fixed`? На production же у вас всё нормально. Чего Вы хотели добиться?

Comment: @vp_arth  я хотел, чтобы пункты меню по их div'у перемещались при скролле)

Comment: Ну вот этот вопрос и нужно было задавать) `max-height/overflow` скорее всего... *И почините текст в "О нас"*

Comment: @vp_arth Хорошо, починю))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приблизительно так? цвета думаю поменяете

```css
ul {
  padding-top: 11px;
}

.spisok {
  height: 300px;
 /*width: 21.1%;*/
  position:fixed;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  /*margin-top: -73%;*/
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px solid #000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}
.spisok::-webkit-scrollbar-button { 
background-image:url(''); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
width:6px; 
height:0px 
} 

.spisok::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
background-color:#32312e; 
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000 inset; 
} 

.spisok::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
border-radius: 5px; 
background-color:#ffcb17; 
box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #fff inset; 
background-image:url('https://yraaa.ru/_pu/24/59610063.png'); 
background-position:center; 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
} 

.spisok::-webkit-resizer{ 
background-image:url(''); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
width:7px; 
height:0px 
} 

.spisok::-webkit-scrollbar{ 
width: 11px; 
}
.spisok li {
  width: 195px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 13.2px;
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
  color: rgba(222, 222, 222 .1);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}

.spisok ul li a p {
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.text-div {
  width: 158px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spisok">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" id="oblacheniya" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/oblacheniya.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Облачения</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/podrizniki.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Подризники</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/stihari.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Стихари</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/ryasi.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing, ryasi">Рясы</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/podryasniki.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Подрясники</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/golovniye_ubori.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Головные уборы</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/for_monahov.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Для монахов</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/kresh_nabory.php">
        <p>Крещальные наборы</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/vench_nabory.php">
        <p>Венчальные наборы</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/obl_for_hrama.php">
        <p>Облачения для храма</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/vishitiye_kresty.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Вышитые кресты</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="ugol">
      <a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/ugol.php">
        <p><span class="letter-spacing">Кадильный уголь</span></p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Как я понял, @Quick Brown Fox нужно не spisok делать fixed, а именно li

Comment: тогда просто забрать из .spisok position:fixed;

Comment: @klifort почему-то при копировании Ваших параметров в стили страницы пропадает меню вообще с экрана

Comment: height: 300px;
    width: 246px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: -100%;
    background-color: #7B2019;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
    border-left: 0px solid #000;
    border-right: 15px solid #000;

Comment: высоты дайте фиксированую - 300рх, 500рх. Потому что при 100% у вас не будет скролла и блок меню будет на всю высоту списка в стиле просто добавьте  'overflow-y: scroll;' и подправьте ширину так как у вас добавиться скролл

Comment: @klifort я опять всё не так объяснил наверное) Вот ссылочка, записал, как надо, проблема лишь в том, что пункты меню в одно смешались https://youtu.be/DYKxucwgFvc

Comment: .spisok ul {position:fixed;} фиксируйте только ul в блоку spisok

Comment: добавил коментарии к вашему видео

Comment: @klifort, подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать, чтобы пункты меню не выходили на футер, как в этом видео https://youtu.be/rKZ1dO_yE1A?

Comment: @klifort давайте, я задам вопрос новый, чтобы галочку там поставить Вам

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то нужно делать у класса spisok fixed, а не у li, сейчас li зафиксированы:

```css
ul {
  padding-top: 11px;
}

.spisok {
  overflow:auto;
  position: fixed;
  height: 400px;
  width: 238px;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  /*margin-top: -73%;*/
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px solid #000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}

.spisok li {
  width: 195px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 13.2px;
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
  color: rgba(222, 222, 222 .1);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}

.spisok ul li a p {
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.text-div {
  width: 158px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spisok">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="text-div" id="oblacheniya" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/oblacheniya.php">
     <p><span class="letter-spacing">Облачения</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/podrizniki.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Подризники</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/stihari.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Стихари</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/ryasi.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing, ryasi">Рясы</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/podryasniki.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Подрясники</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/golovniye_ubori.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Головные уборы</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/for_monahov.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Для монахов</span></p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/kresh_nabory.php"><p>Крещальные наборы</p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/vench_nabory.php"><p>Венчальные наборы</p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div"href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/obl_for_hrama.php"><p>Облачения для храма</p></a></li>
    <li><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/vishitiye_kresty.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Вышитые кресты</span></p></a></li>
    <li id="ugol"><a class="text-div" href="http:///test.ru/left_menu/ugol.php"><p><span class="letter-spacing">Кадильный уголь</span></p></a></li>
   </ul> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68823/discussion-on-answer-by-artem55555p---li----position).